# How do I upload an arbitrary file via HTTP(S) with Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to upload some files generated by Bazel (tarball, and some flat files) to Artifactory.

These aren't specially packaged files, so there aren't any included rules that I can use/find (e.g. maven).

What I am currently using to build the tarball:

```py
filegroup(
    name = "pipeline_helm_chart",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
)

genrule(
    name = "pipeline_helm_package",
    srcs = [
        "pipeline_helm_chart",
    ],
    outs = ["pipeline-0.1.7.tgz"],
    cmd = "helm init --client-only &>/dev/null && helm package -d $(@D) kubernetes/chart/templates/pipeline",
)
```

Ideally, what I would like is:

```py
http_push(
  name = "push",
  srcs = [":pipeline_helm_package"],
  dest = "https://example.com/upload",
)
```

Currently the only way forward that I see is writing a shell script, wrapping it in a `sh_binary`, then using a `genrule` to apply it. But it seems convoluted for something so simple.

It seems like [this Github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1372) may target what I'm looking for, but I don't see that it went anywhere for generic POSTs.

Am I missing something?